# Div won't get resized by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, animation, position, size

This must look like a ridiculous question, especially when this is my job, but there are certain subtleties i don't get about CSS and JavaScript positioning and sizing.

I have a function that "animates" objects (change their properties using a given easing function). Each time the animation progresses, a callback which is supposed to resize a test div is called, but the div remains as is. It must be very simple but i just don't get it.

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sd9tJ/

And a piece of code so i can submit the question :D

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var surface = {w : 100, h : 100};

    var $div = $('#test');

    $t.animate(surface, {w : 200, h : 200}, 2000, $t.easing.linear, function() {
        document.body.innerHTML += '('+Math.round(surface.w)+'/'+Math.round(surface.h)+')';
        $div.css({
            width  : Math.round(surface.w) + 'px',
            height : Math.round(surface.h) + 'px'
        });
    });
});
```

The values are correct, but the style doesn't want to update, so i assume it is CSS related.

Any idea ?

Tahnks for your help :)

Comment: I believe the animate method accepts up to 4 arguments, not 5.

Comment: The animate function is described in the fiddle i linked. Here are its parameters : `function(subject, target, duration, easing, onchange)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in that debugging technique:

```
    document.body.innerHTML += ... ;
```

That picks up the original HTML of the `<div>` and re-adds it as it originally stood at page load time. Take that out, and it works fine.

*edit* — the reason that things work if you use `$('#test')` in the handler is that it causes jQuery to go out and find the element again.  Thus, it finds the updated one, and things work.

The reason that adding to the document like that causes problems is that it's the same as:

```
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + whatever;
```

Fetching the current `innerHTML` gets you the page *without the style updates* to the element. It then re-creates the entire page DOM.  Use `console.log()`, or else make a special element on the page and update its HTML alone.

Comment: Thanks it works. Isn't document.body.innerHTML supposed to be updated ?

Comment: So that means the style is stored inside the HTML ? Isn't jQuery modifying the style property of the element ?

Comment: The style property is modified, but those modifications are not reflected by what you get back from the `.innerHTML` property. (Why? I don't know.)

Answer (score 2):

Change it to:

```
   $('#test').css({
        width  : Math.round(surface.w) + 'px',
        height : Math.round(surface.h) + 'px'
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but why ? The div is static, i can cache it. EDIT: i tried as you said and it works. I don't understand why. Can you explain me please ?

Comment: Actually it does, and i don't get why.

Comment: I'm not entierly sure, I would suspect it's an issue of trying to save a jquery object to a native var? you can always store the name of the div instead of the object, such as: var `myDiv = "#test";`, then call with: `$(myDiv).css(....`

Comment: Caching is widly used and has always been working with everything i did. This div is not dinamically created and it's reference is stored once the document is fully loaded so i don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: No, honestly it surprised me too lol, but thought I would let you know as it was indeed a 'solution' ;)

Comment: @Alfie apologies - yes it would work, but it's not the real cause :)